# Undefined control sequence `\verylarge`

Tags: latex, pdflatex

I have an error when I use `\verylarge\textbf`. Can someone please help me resolve it?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}    
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[]    
\verylarge\textbf{4.3 SIMULATION OF MAINTENANCE PROBLEMS}\\
\vspace{6pt}

This section illustrates the use of simulation in maintenance problems.\\
\begin{center}
    \verylarge SAMPLE PROBLEM
\end{center}

4.13. A plant has a large number of similar machines. The machines break-down are independent of each other. Once a machine breaks-down, it has to be taken out of production till the time it is replaced. On the basis of the past data, the following distributions have been constructed:
\vspace{16pt}    
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
\hline  

\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}\large{No. of break-downs}\\ per hour\end{tabular} & Probability & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Repair time in hrs.\\ per break-down\end{tabular} & Probability \\ \hline \vspace{3pt}
0 & 0.900 & 1 & 0.100 \\ 
1 & 0.085 & 2 & 0.240 \\ 
2 & 0.012 & 3 & 0.450 \\ 
3 & 0.003 & 4 & 0.165 \\ 
\multicolumn{1}{l}{} &  & 5 & 0.040 \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{} &  & 6 & 0.005 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\parindent 0px
Each hour that a machine remains idle due to being, or waiting, to be repaired, it costs the plant Rs. 80 per hour by way of lost production. If a repairman is paid at Rs. 8 per hour, how many repairmen should be hired by the company to service, the machine break-downs?. For the purpose, simulate the system for 50-hour period and use the following random numbers,reading starting with he NW corner :
\parindent 0px

\end{document}
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: @rdelrossi The error is `Undefined control sequence. \verylarge`

Answer (score 0):

Like the error says, the macro `\verylarge` does not exists.

If you want larger than `\large` text, try `\Large`, `\LARGE`, `\huge` or `\Huge`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}    

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[]    
{\Huge\textbf{4.3 SIMULATION OF MAINTENANCE PROBLEMS}\par}

\vspace{6pt}

This section illustrates the use of simulation in maintenance problems.

\begin{center}
    \Huge SAMPLE PROBLEM
\end{center}

4.13. A plant has a large number of similar machines. The machines break-down are independent of each other. Once a machine breaks-down, it has to be taken out of production till the time it is replaced. On the basis of the past data, the following distributions have been constructed:
\vspace{16pt}    
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
\hline  

\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}{\large No. of break-downs}\\ per hour\end{tabular} & Probability & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Repair time in hrs.\\ per break-down\end{tabular} & Probability \\ \hline \vspace{3pt}
0 & 0.900 & 1 & 0.100 \\ 
1 & 0.085 & 2 & 0.240 \\ 
2 & 0.012 & 3 & 0.450 \\ 
3 & 0.003 & 4 & 0.165 \\ 
\multicolumn{1}{l}{} &  & 5 & 0.040 \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{} &  & 6 & 0.005 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\parindent 0px
Each hour that a machine remains idle due to being, or waiting, to be repaired, it costs the plant Rs. 80 per hour by way of lost production. If a repairman is paid at Rs. 8 per hour, how many repairmen should be hired by the company to service, the machine break-downs?. For the purpose, simulate the system for 50-hour period and use the following random numbers,reading starting with he NW corner :
\parindent 0px

\end{document}
```

Some other comments about your code:

- Please have a look at some introductory material about latex, for example https://www.learnlatex.org/ . The most basic principle of latex is to keep content and format separated. Don't clutter your latex code with all these formatting instructions, manual numbering etc. Instead use the appropriate macros to insert sections etc and they will automatically give the desired font sizes and spacing.
- Also don't abuse `\\` for line breaks outside of `tabular` (and similar) environments.
- no idea why most of your document is wrapped in a `table` environment
- instead of this terrible complicated nesting of tables, have a look at fixed with table column or at the `tabularray` package. They make multiline cells much easier
- syntax like `\large{...}` is wrong, large is a switch and does not take an argument. Use `{\large ...}` instead.
- most of the manual vertical spaces you try to insert won't do what you think they do because you are not properly closing your paragraphs with empty lines.